# MultiThreading - Abrindo nova janela em WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

[image]

Eu queria saber se algum de vcs sabe resolver esse erro maldito, (eu quero abrir uma outra window mas ela da esse erro na hora de iniciar) = podem ajudar?

Comment: Se você postar o código talvez de para dar uma ajudada mas assim fica difícil, poste o código.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não uso mais que 1 janela para aplicações, apenas uso a janela principal e preencho ela com usercontrols vinculados a ViewModels no modelo MVVM, mas geralmente quando se trata de usar thread diferente voce tem que usar com `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`

veja meu exemplo para trocar a cor de fundo de um popup de mensagem (tipo Toast)

`TempBackgroundColor.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => TempBackgroundColor = corfundo);`

como mencionado pelo `Anderson Henrique` sem mais informações não podemos ajudar

um chute no escuro (e sem testar nada) eu usaria algo assim:

```
var w = new Window();
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => w.Show());
```

O `this` no caso é a sua `MainWindow`.